# Why isn't a variable nil right after declaration?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I didn't allocated any memories. Why doesn't my date is equal to nil.

[image]

Comment: value 'nil' is not assigned to object types by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because is not nil, its created, its having a place in your memory, but it doenst have a correct value. That date would be nil when you do

```
biggerDate = nil
```

It happens the same with all objects, if you do

```
NSObject *myObject;
```

myObject is NOT nil.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer is not nil because you are not using ARC, and Antonio's answer is right.

With ARC, variables are automatically initialised to nil.